# How to attach to running Popen process

Tags: python, popen

I have a shell script that runs for a while and then takes an input.
I want to create the process:

```
process = subprocess.Popen( 
     '/my/longscript/wait.sh', 
     shell=True, 
     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
     universal_newlines=True 
 )                                                                                                                                                                                   

process                                                                                                                                                                             
<subprocess.Popen at 0x7fb7b319ef60>

process.pid                                                                                                                                                                         
10248
```

And then in a different session attach to this process and send it some stdin. How can I reattach to the process, using the pid, or how do I do this?

```
running_process = subprocess.attach_to_my_old_process(pid=10248)???
running_process.communicate(input='someinput')
```

Comment: I think for this you will have to use a named pipe. Redirect stdin of the process to read from that pipe and have the other process feed data into that named pipe.

Comment: And how exactly do I go about this? I posted another question, if you could help me out, would be much appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132778/how-to-use-fifo-named-pipe-as-stdin-in-popen-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer: you have to use a named pipe for this.

How this can be done was done I answered in your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132778/how-to-use-fifo-named-pipe-as-stdin-in-popen-python).