# How to use fifo named pipe as stdin in Popen python

Tags: python, popen

How do I make Popen use a fifo named pipe as stdin?

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

FNAME = 'myfifo'
os.mkfifo(FNAME, mode=0o777)
f = os.open(FNAME, os.O_RDONLY)

process = subprocess.Popen(
    'wait2.sh',
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin=f,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
)

while process.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("process.stdin", process.stdin)
```

If I run this script and in a terminal window

```
echo "Something" > myfifo
```

The process exits with `process.stdin None`. It seems its not getting the stdin from the fifo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), the `Popen.stdin` is only not `None` if the argument for that field was `PIPE`, which is not the case in your code.

This code works fine for me, it prints "Line 1" and "Line 2" (from the child process) as expected

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

FNAME = 'myfifo'
os.mkfifo(FNAME, mode=0o777)

# Open read end of pipe. Open this in non-blocking mode since otherwise it
# may block until another process/threads opens the pipe for writing.
stdin = os.open(FNAME, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)

# Open the write end of pipe.
tochild = os.open(FNAME, os.O_WRONLY)
print('Pipe open (%d, %d)' % (stdin, tochild))

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['/usr/bin/cat'],
    shell=True,
    stdout=None,
    stdin=stdin,
    stderr=None,
    universal_newlines=True,
)
print('child started: %s (%s)' % (str(process), str(process.stdin)))

# Close read end of pipe since it is not used in the parent process.
os.close(stdin)

# Write to child then close the write end to indicate to the child that
# the input is complete.
print('writing to child ...')
os.write(tochild, bytes('Line 1\n', 'utf-8'))
os.write(tochild, bytes('Line 2\n', 'utf-8'))
print('data written')
os.close(tochild)

# Wait for child to complete.
process.wait()
os.unlink(FNAME)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me also. In the meantime I implemented something using screen, but I will take a look at this. Very interesting.